# How to use documentReference in fragment on android studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

i try to use fragment in homeactivity.java. then i copy the code from old ProfileActivity.java into this new profilefragment.java. then i get this error. everything else is fine.
how to use documentreference in fragment

this is my fragment_profile.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".HomeActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/verifyMsg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Email Not Verified!"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/resendCode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="VERIFY NOW"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/verifyMsg" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_top_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="Your Profile"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_text_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Your Name"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_text_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Your Email Address"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_text_username" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_text_phone_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Phone Number"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_text_email" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="111dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_top_text"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.045"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_text_username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Usename"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_text_name" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my ProfileFragment.java Code

```
 package com.infinite.estudy;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
    import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
    import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
    import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
    import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;

    public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

        TextView fullName, username, email, phoneNumber, verifyMsg;
        FirebaseAuth fAuth;
        FirebaseFirestore fStore;
        String userID;
        Button resendCode;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

            fullName = v.findViewById(R.id.profile_text_name);
            username = v.findViewById(R.id.profile_text_username);
            email = v.findViewById(R.id.profile_text_email);
            phoneNumber = v.findViewById(R.id.profile_text_phone_number);

            fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

            resendCode = v.findViewById(R.id.resendCode);
            verifyMsg = v.findViewById(R.id.verifyMsg);

            userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            final FirebaseUser user = fAuth.getCurrentUser();

            DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("Users").document(userID);
            documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this,new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    email.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("email"));
                    fullName.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("fName"));
                    phoneNumber.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("phoneNumber"));
                    username.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("username"));
                }
            });

            if(!user.isEmailVerified()){
                resendCode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                verifyMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                resendCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final View view) {
                        user.sendEmailVerification().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Verification Email Has Been Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.d("tag","onFailure: Email not sent" + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }

            return v;
        }



    }
```

this is the error I get

> error: no suitable method found for
>   addSnapshotListener(ProfileFragment,>) method
>   DocumentReference.addSnapshotListener(Executor,EventListener)
>   is not applicable (argument mismatch; ProfileFragment cannot be
>   converted to Executor) method
>   DocumentReference.addSnapshotListener(Activity,EventListener)
>   is not applicable (argument mismatch; ProfileFragment cannot be
>   converted to Activity) method
>   DocumentReference.addSnapshotListener(MetadataChanges,EventListener)
>   is not applicable (argument mismatch; ProfileFragment cannot be
>   converted to MetadataChanges)

[image: picture]

i put my fragment in homeactivity.java

Comment: `addSnapshotListener` used to accept continuous changes to your reference. Since you need user information once then you can use `documentReference.get().addOnSuccessListener` instead

Comment: thanks, i will try to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this pass getactivity() in DocumentRefrence may be this will solve your issue

```
 DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("Users").document(userID);
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(getActivity(),new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                email.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("email"));
                fullName.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("fName"));
                phoneNumber.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("phoneNumber"));
                username.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("username"));
            }
        });
```